# how to display calender in bootstrap with upcoming events in left side of the calender?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a requirement where i should be displaying calender with current date getting higlighted and display upcoming event of the person in left hand side of the calender using bootstrap. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a calendar already?  You could always look at using Google Calendar it can be embed into any website and its free.

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en

Comment: No...i dont have a calender...Thanks for the reply...i will check this google calender...Using Google calender,is it possible to display events?

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at http://www.innovativetechsolutions.net/website-services/web-development/embed-google-calendar